# AFNetworking for Android

Tags: android, json, image, asynchronous, afnetworking

I am in the process of porting my iOS app to Android, and am now in need of a simple to use asynchronous class set to download JSON data and images.

For iOS I am using AFNetworking which is an amazing tool. Is there anything like that for Android?

Comment: Perhaps this which I just found. http://code.google.com/p/android-query

Comment: Ashley: what did you end up using?

Comment: @just.jimmy I used the one the answer. Also, if you come across it not loading data when going back to previously loaded data, it is because of a circular redirect feature which you need to turn off. (it drove me crazy for a week)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's loop j's async http lib for Android (though I'm not a huge fan) http://loopj.com/android-async-http/. Honestly, best thing is just to use apache httpclient inside of an intentservice so it's async and then deliver the results to your activities, etc through a ResultReceiver.

**UPDATE**

I now recommend Retrofit, an open-source project from Square. I use it and it works very well as a REST client. http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it. May I ask why you don't like it much?

Comment: Any reason you don't like it? Even I would love to know.

Answer (score 6):

You could try [RoboSpice](https://github.com/octo-online/robospice). Give us feedback, if it was, what you needed.

Comment: It looks really good and I may use it in a future app, however, loopj's async lib has already been implemented in the app I was working on. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Another good option could be Volley, networking library introduced on IO 2013 by Google. For more info check this topic: [Volley Android Networking Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16659620/volley-android-networking-library)

Answer (score 1):

This lib is awesome. i think is all you want give a try dude

https://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/AsyncAPI