# Looking for library async http request for android

Tags: android, httprequest

I am looking for something like following code. I know the code below is obviously wrong, I just want to make it clear that what I am looking for.

```
private HttpRequest httpRequest;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // instiantiate the httpRequest
        httpRequest = HttpRequest.init();

        httpRequest.get("http://www.example.com", HttpRequest.callbackFunction(){
            @Override
            public void Result(String err, String recv){
                // done something here 
            }
        });
    }
```

** Must works in background and implement with callback function

** It must be able to be called multiple times on single activity. AsyncTask is not the things I want.

** I don't mind open source library. As long as it achieved what I needs

Comment: What's wrong with multiple AsyncTasks?

Comment: Volley from Google might be worth checking.
Please look at this SO [thread for details][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16659620/volley-android-networking-library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**
This is and old question, Now we have many good Network libs for Android.
[OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/), [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/), [Ion](https://github.com/koush/ion), .....[etc](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/65).

---

Two excellent libs I have used:
1- Android Query ([AQuery](http://code.google.com/p/android-query/))

```
aq.ajax(url, String.class, new AjaxCallback<String>() {
     @Override
     public void callback(String url, String html, AjaxStatus status) {

     }   
});
```

2- [Android Asynchronous Http Client](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/)

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.get("http://www.google.com", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String response) {

    }
});
```