# Why am I keep getting NetworkOnMainThreadException?

Tags: java, android, exception

I've passed through all SO's solution to solve `NetworkOnMainThreadException` Including ASync class - but still something is wrong

Here is my simple code :

**ActivityMain** Class :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    ArrayList<City> alCities = new ArrayList<City>();
    Activity activity=null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        activity=this;

        new MyTask(activity, alCities).execute(); //<--- running ASYNC here
    }
}
```

**MyTask** Class :

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<City>>
{
    ArrayList<City> alCities = null;
    Activity ac = null;

    public MyTask(Activity activity, ArrayList<City> al) //ctor
    {
        alCities = al;
        this.activity= activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<City> doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        try
        {
            Object myJsonObject = Util.getJson("http://jsbin.com/lobel/2.js"); //internet job

                try
                {
                    //...fill array list...
                    return alCities;

                } catch (Exception e)
                {
                    ...
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            ...
        }
        return null;
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<City> alCities)
    {
    ...
    //update UI
    ListView l1 = (ListView) ac.findViewById(R.id.list_view_1);
    ///
    }

}
```

But still  :

[image]

nb :

If I put :

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}
```

It does work :

[image]

**Question**

What am I doing wrong ?

**Full stack trace**  : http://jsbin.com/bilafi/2/edit

All I do is loading json file !

Full code of **onPostExecute** :

```
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<City> alCities)
    {
        CustomArrayAdapter adapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(ac, alCities);

        ListView l1 = (ListView) ac.findViewById(R.id.list_view_1);
        l1.setAdapter(adapter);
        l1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id)
            {
                // Util.Toast(getBaseContext(), "You have selected " + 1);

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: When examining the complete stack trace, at which line of your code does the Exception occur? Is this line inside the `doInBackground` of the AsyncTask?

Comment: Show the full stacktrace, and include it as text, please, not a screenshot! There must be something else you're not showing us. What else is in `onPostExecute()`?

Comment: Most likely you are doing something in `onPostExecute()` that cause `okhttp` to make a network call (maybe a lazy loading call)

Comment: Edited. pasting her it also - full stack trace http://jsbin.com/bilafi/2/edit

Comment: The problems comes from here com.example.listview3.Util.getBitmapFromURL(Util.java:179), nothing to do with the Json file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is where your crash is:

```
at com.example.listview3.Util.getBitmapFromURL(Util.java:179)
at com.example.listview3.CustomArrayAdapter.getView(CustomArrayAdapter.java:67)
```

You have used the `AsyncTask` correctly. However, when filling the list, you're trying to fetch images, *again* using the network. This time, you're not using an `AsyncTask`, hence the `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Comment: But the code itself runs inside the thread no ? I also put the main call in a thread and it still occured. if A calls B and A started within thread , then B also..

Comment: The code placed in `onPostExecute` does not run in the background thread, no. You will have to start another thread for each of the images.

Comment: Yep, there you have it :)

Comment: Just a note, handling image loading for items in a `ListView` can get a bit complex. As views get recycled, you will need to keep track of your request threads to cancel them as well - otherwise you'll end up with the wrong image for a certain item. [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) is a nice library which handles this for you.

Answer (score 3):

From the full stack trace the error source is clear at

`om.example.listview3.CustomArrayAdapter.getView()` where it is trying to load `Bitmap` from URL

i.e.`at com.example.listview3.Util.getBitmapFromURL(Util.java:179)`

`onPostExecute` runs in the main UI thread, that's why you are getting the `NetworkOnMainThreadException`

You might want to consider using [volley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16659620/volley-android-networking-library), it can work on top of okhttp and provides easy to use method for loading images without threading hassles, it was introduced in [Google IO 2013](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325304728)