# How to make a .jar out of the Volley project?

Tags: android, android-volley

How do I make a .jar file out of the [Volley project](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) ([git repository](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley))?

I have tried to follow the instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16721116/1274911), however running `android update project -p .` in the cloned `volley` folder throws this error:

```
Error: . is not a valid project (AndroidManifest.xml not found).
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The build process for Volley has changed to Gradle. If you just want to use the library without building it, you can get the Jar from Maven or scroll down to the instructions to building it yourself lower in this answer.

**Maven**

An easier way to obtain the Jar file is to download it directly from Maven Central. You can find the latest version with this search:

http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.mcxiaoke.volley%22

At the time of writing the 1.0.19 version can be found here:

http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/mcxiaoke/volley/library/1.0.19/library-1.0.19.jar

---

**Gradle**

The new way to do it is to build the project using Gradle.

You can do this by running:

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley
gradle build
```

This will create a file in

```
build\intermediates\bundles\release
```

Then add this file into your libs folder and add it to your project.

Comment: I ended up using another library, so I won't verify the correctness of this answer, but based on the number of upvotes, I assume it is correct, thus accepting. Thank you nevertheless.

Comment: I'm wondering what is the reason for the added step "git checkout 008e0cc8"? What is this doing? Many thanks.

Comment: The reason to add this step is to checkout an old version of the repository before the jar file process was broken. I am updating the answer with an easier way.

Comment: Why library-1.0.15.jar size (90.8 KB) is larger than built jar (84.3 KB)?!

Comment: This is not google tho, is it?
Also I would like to know if you dont mind @Zabri what library did you use finally?

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question, and potentially using old code.  @Sateesh G has the better answer

Comment: incase if you guys dunno where is gradle,
/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.4/bin/gradle (for mine)
also ive to chmod a+x on it before able to use

Answer (score 1):

Before you run the `android update project -p .` command on command prompt first run this command `git checkout 008e0cc8` it would surpress any errors especially the (AndroidManifest.xml not found), then you can now run the `android update project -p .`    it works

Answer (score 0):

They moved the project to gradle. You need to build project using gradle.
You can find the detailed explanation how to make volley jar using gradle command [here](http://androidsrc.net/android-volley-library-tutorial/).

Before you build the volley project you may need to set some environmental variable like adding gradle location to PATH or setting ANDROID_HOME.

Answer (score 0):

@Sateesh G answer is the better answer.  Here are the steps I used to build volley as an aar on OS X.  (Assuming you already have git, gradle, and android dev tools setup and working)

```
export ANDROID_HOME=~/.android-sdk/android-sdk-macosx
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley
cd volley
```

Configured roblectric and its dependencies

```
echo 'emulateSdk=18'>>src/test/resources/org.robolectric.Config.properties
cat<<END>rules.gradle
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.apache.maven:maven-ant-tasks:2.1.3'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.4'
}
END
```

Build the aar

```
gradle wrapper
./gradlew clean build
```

Output files will be located under

```
build/outputs/aar
```

Finally to include the resulting aar files in your Android project; copy the volley-release.aar file to the libs subdirectory under your project and add the following to your projects build.gradle file

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

compile('com.android.volley:volley-release:1.0.0@aar')
```