# Eclipse + volley can't import the library

Tags: android, eclipse, android-volley

I'm tying to import the volley library, but I've encountered several problems.
I'm working on windows.

I tried to compile it, but when I launch

```
android update project -p .
```

I get:

```
Error: C:\Users\UserName\git\volley is not a valid project (AndroidManifest.xml no
t found).
```

I've also tried importing it directly in eclipse as a library. What I've done is:

- clone the repository with eclipse
- import it as an android project from existing code
- mark it as a library
- add the dependecy to my project

but the project I'm coding can't find the source codes, in fact the src folder of the library in package explorer is empty

what am I missing?

Comment: That "Eclipse ADT" is no longer supported, and Android Studio is the new official IDE for Android development.

Comment: I know, but that's a university project. I don't want to move the whole project to Android studio now. Is there a way I can get this library working on eclipse?

Comment: Is your ADT/SDK up to date anyway? Since volley framework follows the most recent way of placing files. The AndroidManifest.xml is indeed placed inside volley/src/main.

Comment: yes it is... I upload everything periodically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even I faced many times the same problem, So usually I download jar file. Refer this link [SO : Volley Project - Jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27487972/how-to-make-a-jar-out-of-the-volley-project).  Download the link provided by @Ankit.

Comment: thanks, that worked. I'm not sure if it's the way to do it but I'll keep it

I wonder why they don't include it in the SDK

Answer (score 2):

If it helps you can use [this jar](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1jt914nfqrok5fl/Volley_7-1-15.jar?dl=1) file which I extracted out from some project and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You must tell your project to depend on your library project. To apply this you must have your library project imported to Eclipse already, then you right click on your project to open its preferences screen. There you will find Android tab to apply the setting.
If you just want to depend on an jar file, you will have to setup the compiler before. For this also head to your project properties and loog for "Java Build Path" and there for Libraries. You may also have to apply "Order & Export" settings afterwhile.

Comment: yes, of course I've done it, I forgot to write this. thank you