# making jar file from Android Volley

Tags: java, android, apache, ant, android-volley

I want to make a jar file for android volley

I have cloned:

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley
```

then I tried :
[image]

I get Build failed.

Can you advice please.thank you.

Comment: volley already has a jar file. May i know the reason why you want to reinvent the same?

Comment: You can build it as an *aar* file as described [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31357048/3765842

Comment: If you want to use Volley in a project, you should just use the correct line in the `dependencies` block in `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 0):

That repository doesn't always have the right structure. As for now I suppose the current version is `android-5.1.1_r2` (May 11 2015). So to build:

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley
cd volley
git checkout b3b7e68
android update project -p .
ant jar
```

You'd need  `sdk/platform-tools/` and `sdk/tools/` in path environment variable for `android update` command to work.

Or if you use gradle you can just add `compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'` in your gradle build.