# Changing the floating action menu icon in Android

Tags: android, floating-action-button, floating-action-menu

I created a set of floating action buttons under a floating action menu, but I can't change the floating action menu icon when I click the floating action button.

How can I change the floating action menu icon in Android?

Comment: put your code here

Comment: Take a look at my answer..!!

Comment: i add a library but no changes

Answer (score 0):

Check properly that you have added the dependency. The official version available in JCenter. Try the below.

```
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
```

refer the [link](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html)

Comment: can you tell it for eclipse

Comment: refer this    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27487972/how-to-make-a-jar-out-of-the-volley-project

Comment: i tried but i get same error but thnx for helping me

Answer (score 0):

Download `volley.jar` from [Here](http://api.androidhive.info/volley/volley.jar).

1. Right click on your project.
2. Go to properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries tab & click on `Add External JARs..`
3. Select your downloaded `Volley.jar` & there you go you can use volley function easily now.

[image]

**Though i have given this, I strictly recommend you to migrate from eclipse to Android Studio.**

Answer (score -1):

Your not found StringRequest class from volley library. Please check application property and check have you add library or .jar file?

Comment: i add  a volley lib  but i get an same issue java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest

Comment: Put the same version android support library in your project and library projects you included and clean build.

Comment: open your appcompat_v7 library and in this lib folder copy the v7.jar or v-4and past it from your project lib folder. then clean the project and run it.