# POST request with JSON body in Volley Android

Tags: android, android-volley

I am using volley library. I have the following API url http://example.com/project/contriller/ and need to post the json request as body `{"function":"getList","parameters":{"latitude":"10.0086575","longitude":"76.3187739"},"token":""}`to it.

How can send it using Volley?

Comment: Just have look into this for your answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/16795805/4653447

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Volley Android Networking Library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16659620/volley-android-networking-library)

Comment: These are the ordinary JSON Request. I want to request JSON as Body,,,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check below two options for that.

**Option1**

Try to send data in Map variable as below, and put this code just above you are calling request using Post as below.

```
        Map<String, String> postParam= new HashMap<String, String>();
        postParam.put("function", "getList");
        postParam.put("latitude", "10.0086575");
        postParam.put("token", "");

        new JsonObjectRequest(url, postParam, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() { ... });
```

**option2**

You can use below to send direct JSON.

```
        final JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject("{\"function\":\"getList\",\"parameters\":{\"latitude\":\"10.0086575\",\"longitude\":\"76.3187739\"},\"token\":\"\"}");

        new JsonObjectRequest(url, jsonData, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() { ... });
```