# How to send JSON file in API as a parameter in android?

Tags: android, json, api, parameter-passing, httpurlconnection

How to send JSON file in API as a parameter in android?

like

```
{
"param1" : "xyz123",
"file":"demo.json"
}
```

I have to send this JSON in an API. Here demo.json is file.

Comment: You should check this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/a/18050865/5345482

Comment: Check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37468403/post-request-with-json-body-in-volley-android/37475649#37475649

Answer (score 0):

You can send the json file as a multipart upload. Libraries like [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) can make making API calls simpler.