# Android Volley callback after multiple request completes

Tags: android, sqlite, android-volley, asynccallback

I have made a splash screen where im syncing data from server to sqlite. I have to make few requests (lets say 5 request for 5 tables), and then the splash screen goes off and main activity starts. Please share some ideas as Im clueless how to achieve this. I have left no stone unturned in stackoverflow but could not find a perfect workaround.

Answer (score 0):

[Add Volley https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16659620/volley-android-networking-library?rq=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16659620/volley-android-networking-library?rq=1)

Then you can make calls from volley

```
     JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new   JsonObjectRequest(com.android.volley.Request.Method.POST, Url__, ipObject,
                            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                listener.resultJson(null, response);
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    }
```

listener.resultJson(null, response); will get the responce from server and save this responce to your Sqlite.Finally close your Spalsh .

Comment: Yes, I know using volley library and make a simple request. Im asking how to make 5 concurrent requests and start main activity **after all the requests are completed**.

Comment: send your all requests to 
mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
jsonObjReq.setTag("TAG");
mRequestQueue .add(jsonObjReq);
OR
Create new Thread for Service call

Comment: It will be helpful with an example. I am still unable to get it where should I start the intent for main activity? Thanks